# System Memory Reporting

Tags: server, memory, ram

When logging into my Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS (VPS), I get some nice stats upon login (or `$ landscape-sysinfo)`:

```
System information as of Tue Nov  6 05:41:06 EST 2012

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           90
  Usage of /:   22.3% of 8.51GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 25%               IP address for eth0: XX.XX.XX.XX
  Swap usage:   7%
```

If I run: `$ free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           487        419         67          0          9        117
-/+ buffers/cache:        293        193
Swap:          255         19        236
```

I see that the memory is different. I'm running a Virtual Private Server that in which I pay for 512Mb RAM. Is that the difference I'm seeing here, that 'landscape-sysinfo' calculates based on the entire machine and 'free' calculates based on my allowed quota?

I saw a similar post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9733/what-is-the-difference-between-the-memory-usage-report-in-system-monitor-and-the) but it doesn't solve my exact issue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have the same problem on bare metal, so appears to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/landscape-client/+bug/1075619

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the issue.

/proc/meminfo reports the same memory info that landscape-sysinfo does.

Here's the thing, 'free' reports a lot of memory info. To get the data supplied by 'free' to match both landscape-sysinfo and /proc/meminfo, the calculation is:

(used - [-/+ buffers/cache]) / total

the -/+ buffers/cache value is the one right below 'used'

Now your % free should match what is reported by landscape-sysinfo